# Updating Secure service on Portal for ArcGIS with PortalPy and requests?

Tags: arcgis-portal, request

I'm using the below [Portalpy](https://github.com/Esri/portalpy) code to update my secure Feature Services on ESRI Portal which have a stored password.  The return on `print post_url` in the script is: `https://somedomain.com/portal/sharing/rest/content/users/siteadmin/f43542fd62c74db6997a5d16c9eec16e/items/c3aa864f30ee4d8fbc5241134d35762c/update` with a satus code of `200`.  The above URL is identical when I do it manually and watch it with fiddler.  However the script is not changing the U/P in portal.  I assume I am passing the parameters incorrectly, but am following the user docs for construction and parameters.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Portal: 10.3v

```
import portalpy
import requests
import json

#Login Info
username = 'XXXX'
password = 'XXXX'
portal_url = 'https:/somedomain.com/portal'
portal = portalpy.Portal(portal_url, username, password)

#get token
token = portal.generate_token(username, password, expiration=60)

#set new username
new_username = 'newu'
new_password = 'newp'

payload = {'serviceUsername':new_username, 'servicePassword':new_password}

#print  portal.get_folder_id('siteadmin')


#Search for layers
search = portal.search('Feature Service')

for i in search:
    try:
        a = i['url'].split('/')
        folder_id = portal.get_folder_id('siteadmin', a[9])
        post_url = portal.resturl + 'content/users/siteadmin/' + folder_id + '/items/' + i['id'] + '/update'
        print post_url
        post = requests.post(post_url, data=payload)
        print post.status_code
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to pass the token in the payload.  It should have been

```
payload = {'serviceUsername':new_username, 'servicePassword':new_password, 'token': token}
```